# jquery uitabs with images

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

how can I use images in a jquery UI tab instead of text? when using text the selected tab has a different styling than a nonselected one. What css element(s) do I have to modify to make this useful for tabs that have images in them?

I tried something here but it is not very visible which tab is selected at the moment:

http://jsfiddle.net/8Cmuf/16/

html:

```
<div id="dgTabs" style="width: 500px;">
            <ul>
                <li><a id="a1" href="tab-1"> 
                    <img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2012/10/30/3754903/umbrella_tn-90x60.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a id="a2" href="tab-2">
                    <img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2012/10/30/3754903/umbrella_tn-90x60.jpg" /> </a></li>
                      <li><a id="a3" href="tab-1"> 
                    <img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2012/10/30/3754903/umbrella_tn-90x60.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a id="a4" href="tab-2">
                    <img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2012/10/30/3754903/umbrella_tn-90x60.jpg" /> </a></li>
                    <li><a id="a5" href="tab-1"> 
                    <img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2012/10/30/3754903/umbrella_tn-90x60.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a id="a6" href="tab-2">
                    <img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2012/10/30/3754903/umbrella_tn-90x60.jpg" /> </a></li>
                      <li><a id="a7" href="tab-1"> 
                    <img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2012/10/30/3754903/umbrella_tn-90x60.jpg" /></a></li>
                <li><a id="a8" href="tab-2">
                    <img src="http://images.smh.com.au/2012/10/30/3754903/umbrella_tn-90x60.jpg" /> </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>​
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not to use image withing LI tag, instead try using different CSS class.

Try using default jQuery UI code given here http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default

And then added few classes in CSS that will help you, see below code...

> <style>
>
> .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li{ height: 35px; width: 42px; }
>
> .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ico1{ background:url(http://jqueryui.com/web-base-template/themes/jquery/i/jq-nav-icons.png) no-repeat;
>   background-position: -40px 1px; }
>
> .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ico2{ background:url(http://jqueryui.com/web-base-template/themes/jquery/i/jq-nav-icons.png) no-repeat; background-position: 8px 1px; }
>
> .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav li.ico3{ background:url(http://jqueryui.com/web-base-template/themes/jquery/i/jq-nav-icons.png) no-repeat; background-position: -91px 1px; }
>
> </style>

Comment: Please assign .icoX classes created in CSS to LI tag to see result, well, I updated it there, please check it now http://jsfiddle.net/5bNV3/3/